# In CSS, is there any way to keep the hover properties for links after overriding the normal state?

Tags: css, styles, hover, hyperlink, state

I have default properties defined for my links like this:

```
a{
    color: blue;
}
a:hover{
    color: red;
}
```

The problem is that I lose the all the hover properties when I do something like this:

```
#header a{
    color: gray;
}
```

So to keep the hover working as I defined it before in the defaults, I'd have to declare it again:

```
#header a:hover{
    color: red;
}
```

Is there any way to do this without loosing the original hover action defined?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, if you want it to work in all browsers, you'll have to override it.

```
a { color:blue; }
a:hover { color:red; }

#header a { color:grey; }
#header a:hover { color:red; }
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/elsom25/ftf2q/).

Alternatively, you can make use of `!important`.  Usually this is a sign that something weird is going on in your css, but this seems to be the only alternative to duplicating your css.

```
a { color:blue; }
a:hover { color:red !important; }

#header a:hover { color:red; }
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/elsom25/QwvGf/).

You could also make use of a css compiler such as [sass](http://sass-lang.com/) or [less](http://lesscss.org/) which would let you *write* it in a manor where you aren't duplicating effort - but that's beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: Hey elsom, thanks for the answer. I tried Jamie's example and it wasn't working as expected. Is it working for you?

Comment: I just tried and unfortunately not - though his new one is a good alternative!

Answer (score 1):

You're over-riding the styles with a cascade.  Putting "#header a" gives that style more weight than the original style.  You can over-ride it with a !important (although I wouldn't recommend it).  [Here's an article that explains this concept](http://webdesign.about.com/od/advancedcss/a/aa062706.htm).

Comment: Micharch, thanks for the answer. I'm aware of specificity and that I could use !important, but I just want to know if there's a way to override the normal state while keeping the hover state.

Comment: You have several options such as assigning them a class or id and then targeting that way to increase their specificity.  So for example, if it's a specific group, give them a class like "special_hover" and then target it.  This would give that specific group greater weight and make it more likely that they'll be targeted correctly.  There's no way to really over-ride the cascade.  You have to target things and give them weight. Personally, I try to avoid getting into specificity as much as possible.  But in this case I can't think of another way to really do it.

Answer (score 1):

One way you can do this is to specify the default style as `!important`.

Using `!important` is usually a sure fire sign that your code can be improved however in this context, and without re-defining the styles, it seems like the best choice (best I know of right now).

```
a:hover{
    color:blue !important;
}
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/4Lmxq/1/)

Also note that if you do go down the route of using the specific selector that you can combine both selectors together to reduce code duplication.

```
a:hover, #header a:hover{ color: red;}
```